# Desplegar una serie de numeros pares e impares en java

Tags: java

Eh realizado un programa en java que hace que el usuario ingrese un numero total de numeros para evaluar, si ingresa 4, tendra que introducir 4 veces cualquier numero, y de allí verificar si es par o no, uno por uno, pero, cuando trato de desplegar en seguido la sucesión de los pares e inpares, solo me despliega el ultimo valor que ingrese ¿Como puedo hacer para que en el despliegue sea algo como esto? 
Ingrese el numero de numeros a evaluar:

4

Ingrese num1:

2

Ingrese num2:

4

ingrese num3:

3

ingrese num4:

5

Los numeros pares son:

2, 4

Los numeros impares son:

3, 5

```
    int li, num;
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de nuemros a evaluar: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    li= sc.nextInt();
                    int np = 0;
                    int nip=05;

    for(int i=1; i<=li; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Ingrese su numero #" + i);
        num = sc.nextInt();
        if(num%2==0)
        {
            np = num;
        }
        else
        {
            nip= num;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Los numeros pares son: ");
    System.out.println(np);
    System.out.println("Los numeros inpares pares son: "+ nip);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías guardar los números en arrays diferentes, dependiendo de si el número es par o impar, lo que pasa es que guardas los números en una sola variable y no se guardan los demás, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de una posible solución:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> pares = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> inpares = new ArrayList<>();
    int li, num;
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de nuemros a evaluar: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    li = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i <= li; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese su numero #" + i);
        num = sc.nextInt();
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            pares.add(num);
        } else {
            inpares.add(num);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Los numeros pares son: ");
    for(Integer n : pares){ System.out.print(n); }
    System.out.println("Los numeros inpares pares son: ");
    for(Integer n : inpares){ System.out.print(n); }
```

- Como ves defino dos ArrayList de tipo Integer, para contener números
- Dentro del ciclo elijo donde guardar el número, mediante el método `.add(...)` de la clase ArrayList
- Por último solo resta imprimirlos, mediante un ciclo ForEach, que básicamente me retorna cada uno de los objetos del ArrayList y lo imprimo.

Es una solución sencilla, igual lo puedes hacer sin ArrayList, pero igual espero te sirva de algo, saludos.

**SOLUCIÓN SIN ARRAYS**

```
    String pares = "";
    String impares = "";
    int li, num;
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de nuemros a evaluar: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    li = sc.nextInt();       

    for (int i = 1; i <= li; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese su numero #" + i);
        num = sc.nextInt();
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            pares += num + " ";
        } else {
            impares += num + " ";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Los numeros pares son: " + pares);

    System.out.println("\nLos numeros inpares pares son: " + impares);
```

Esta es una forma más sencilla, unicamente concatenas los números a cadenas diferentes con el operador +=, que es igual a decir `cadena = cadena + "..."`
y luego se imprime el resultado de cada una.

Comment: Existe alguna solución donde no intervegan, lo que pasa es que aun no nos enseñan nada de eso aun, y no puedo tomar ese camino

Comment: Claro, deja actualizo mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudaria muchisimo

Comment: Es necesario que no use arrays ?

Comment: Sí, muy necesario, es por eso que pido ayuda

Comment: Ya lo edité amigo, la solución es solo concatenar los números a una cadena, para que quede guardado, y luego lo imprimes, saludos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me ah servido de mucho

Answer (score 0):

tu problema es que estas usando una sola variable para almacenar los diferentes números y al entrar otro se te van a remplazar, utiliza un array que la forma de declararlos seria lo siguiente:

```
    int[] num;
    num = new int[li] //donde li es la cantidad de números a evaluar
```

recuerda que al manejar arrays siempre se debe comenzar a contar desde 0 es decir num[0] seria el primer valor ingresado, los arrays se pueden recorrer con un for

```
for(int i = 0, i < li, i++){
    System.out.println("Ingrese su numero #" + i + 1); // para mostrar desde 1
    num[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
if(num[i]%2==0)
    {
        np = num[i]; /*tambien diria que hagas de np un array para guardar diferentes valores */
    }
```

esa seria una forma de hacerlo

Comment: Lo que pasa es que, aun no nos an enseñado nada acerca de los arrays

Comment: No existe alguna otra manera, que no los involucre?

Comment: De hecho, se puede, usando strings o directamente diciendo si el número es par o no luego de ingresarlo.